# Change from long writing to jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new with jquery, I want to do this

Here is Html code :

```
        <div class="content-holder">
        <a href="#" class="expand-content-link2">ジパングカジノ</a>
        <div class="hidden-content2">
            <div style="width:100%">
                <div style="width:20% ; float:left;height: 100px;"><img src="http://54.248.103.159/minnano-casino/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cropped-download2.jpg"></div>
                <div style="width:75%; float: right; height: 100px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>ジパングカジノ</li>
                        <li>対応端末：<a class="button0" href="#">日本語</a>
                        <a class="button1" href="#">PC</a>
                        <a class="button2" href="#">Smartphone </a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.zipangcasino.com/jp ">URL：http://www.zipangcasino.com/jp</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and so on.....

```
      jQuery(".expand-content-link2").click(function() {
                    jQuery(".content-holder").find(".hidden-content2", this).toggle();
                    return false;
                });
                jQuery(".expand-content-link3").click(function() {
                    jQuery(".content-holder").find(".hidden-content3", this).toggle();
                    return false;
                });
                  jQuery(".expand-content-link4").click(function() {
                    jQuery(".content-holder").find(".hidden-content4", this).toggle();
                    return false;
                });
```

it is works perfectly, But I think you will another way to do it without long like that.

Anyone have idea?

Comment: provide html related

Comment: Can you add corresponding HTML, it'll be helpful to optimize the code

Comment: Use `$('.content-holder a').on('click', function(e) { $(this).next().toggle(); e.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **.closest()**  and **.find()**

```
jQuery("[class^='expand-content-link']").click(function() {
     jQuery(this).closest('.content-holder').find("[class^='hidden-content']").toggle();
     return false;
});
```

or you can use **.next();**

```
jQuery("[class^='expand-content-link']").click(function() {
     jQuery(this).next().toggle();
     return false;
});
```

> Additional : if you need to read about
>   [**Selectors**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: @Tushar I removed it .. but let me say I used to use it like old one to be sure the selector is a  right selector

Comment: You can pass the selector to `next` when you're not sure about HTML structure. Here, OP has shown HTML, so dont' need it.

Comment: Be aware that the attribute selector `[class^=....]` may fail if the `a` elements happen to have multiple classes, for example `<a href="#" class="link expand-content-link2">..`

Comment: @APov my answer ,Peter answer and Tushar code in comment  .. all of them will work in your case.. so please read all of them beside the previous comment from Peter .. I think they will be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer @Tushar gave in the comments:

```
$('.content-holder > a').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```js
$('.content-holder > a').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="content-holder">
        <a href="#" class="expand-content-link2">ジパングカジノ</a>
        <div class="hidden-content2">
            <div style="width:100%">
                <div style="width:20% ; float:left;height: 100px;"><img src="http://54.248.103.159/minnano-casino/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cropped-download2.jpg"></div>
                <div style="width:75%; float: right; height: 100px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>ジパングカジノ</li>
                        <li>対応端末：<a class="button0" href="#">日本語</a>
                        <a class="button1" href="#">PC</a>
                        <a class="button2" href="#">Smartphone </a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.zipangcasino.com/jp ">URL：http://www.zipangcasino.com/jp</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="content-holder">
        <a href="#" class="expand-content-link3">ジパングカジノ</a>
        <div class="hidden-content3">
            <div style="width:100%">
                <div style="width:20% ; float:left;height: 100px;"><img src="http://54.248.103.159/minnano-casino/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cropped-download2.jpg"></div>
                <div style="width:75%; float: right; height: 100px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>ジパングカジノ</li>
                        <li>対応端末：<a class="button0" href="#">日本語</a>
                        <a class="button1" href="#">PC</a>
                        <a class="button2" href="#">Smartphone </a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.zipangcasino.com/jp ">URL：http://www.zipangcasino.com/jp</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```